# Cannot run executable file - SPAZ installer

Tags: installation, executable

After reinstalling my Ubuntu (right now I have 12.04.1) I'm trying to install [SPAZ](http://spacepiratesandzombies.com/), but when I run the installer:

```
gacek@gacek-Vostro-3460:~$ ./spaz-linux-humblebundle-09182012-bin 
bash: ./spaz-linux-humblebundle-09182012-bin: No such file or directory
```

it says there's no such file. But it exist. I've tried to change the ownership of the file, change the access flags for it. The executable flag is also enabled.

Where could be the problem?

Regarding the question, the file exists and it is NOT a directory:

```
gacek@gacek-Vostro-3460:~$ ls -g
razem 168776
drwxrwxrwx  2  1000      4096 Dec 22 23:25 Desktop
(...)
-rwxr-xr-x  1 gacek 157466422 Sep 19 01:15 spaz-linux-humblebundle-09182012-bin
```

Comment: are you sure this `spaz-linux-humblebundle-09182012-bin` is not a DIRECTORY?

Comment: yes, I'm sure. It is a binary file (executable). Before the reinstallation I successfully installed the SPAZ just by executing the file. Right now I cannot and I don't know why

Answer (score -2):

I think that it's just a permission matter, just run this command:

```
chmod +x spaz-linux-humblebundle-09182012-bin
```

and then again:

```
./spaz-linux-humblebundle-09182012-bin
```

Comment: It already has the executable flag - take a look at the `ls`

Answer (score -2):

Rename it `sudo mv spaz-linux-humblebundle-09182012-bin spaz.exe` then launch it with Wine

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me on xubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

Comment: sorry mate,  worked but partially, i installed playonlinux and now works fine.

Comment: btw command is sudo apt-get install playonlinux